Why does my AC drain pipe have an upward-facing elbow at the end?
I have a PVC pipe that drains water from my AC to the outside. It drains onto the ground as it is open on the end. Someone put an elbow on the end of it with the open end of the elbow facing up. It does not appear to be allowing for drainage.  Why would they have put it facing up?

Was the elbow just stuck on there? Or was it actually glued in place? If it was just stuck on there, it might have been inadvertently moved at some point. I have PVC pipes to drain my A/C condensate into a floor drain - 4 elbows involved and thinks get bumped sometimes.

Sounds like a makeshift water trap, possibly to discourage pest entry. That shouldn't block flow, though. Is the pipe otherwise clear?

isherwood is probably right about why it's there.   As to whether it will actually achieve that .. I don't think it would discourage most pests very much, but it will gather debris much better than if pointing down.  At least put another elbow on it facing sideways, like an open p-trap.

Ends like that are mandatory in my area. The AC techs call them "lizard traps"  because they discourage the lizards from running in the pipe, dying and causing a blockage.

The turned up elbow will only block flow if the upstream end (condensate source) is lower than the top of the elbow.
